# Re Running a request in jmeter using IF controller

Tags: if-statement, controller, jmeter, response

I have a http request whose response gives me the following if the code is executed correctly:
  "Status": "0" and "Code": "15"
else "Status" : "1" and "Code": "", then
rerun the above request. If not, the  "Status": "0" and "Code": "15", then It should stop re-running the above request of getSubmission Data and execute the next request.

How do I use if controller for the same?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calls for a while controller

While controller basically checks for the condition until satisfied and then lets the thread move to the subsequent steps

**My Test Plan suggestion**

Place the HTTP request both outside and inside the while loop controller

[image]

Correlate for "Status" using Regular expression extractor:

[image]

Provide below while controller expression

[image]

When you run the test, until status_C becomes 0, the while controller will keep polling for that request. You can include additional conditional statements including more variables like "Code"

You may want to include a timer for polling requests if necessary

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Regular Expression Extractor is getting applied to **both** requests, you might want to move it to be a child of one of the requests, see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more details
2. If you're getting responses in [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) it makes more sense to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
3. If you need to repeat the request until it provides the expected response:

   - put it under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set the number of loops to whatever maximum amount of tries you want. Tick `infinite` or put `-1` if you want to loop forever
   - Add If Controller and put the [__jexl3() expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like `${__jexl3(${Status}==0 && ${Code}==15,)}` there
   - Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as the child of the If Controller and set it to `Break Current Loop`